# Path change results with source files getting searched under wrong file

Tags: html, angular

On my `index.html` file I have a script like below:

```
  <script src="assets/adminlte/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

And this works without any issues on any page, unless I specifically type in something inside the url bar and navigate from there.

This is when I navigate inside the system, using `routerLink`:

[image]

This is when I refresh the page:

[image]

What happens is, it tries to find the assets folder in `https://localhost:4200/show/` rather than `https://localhost:4200/`.

My `angular.json` file is like below:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Portal": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/portal",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "local": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Portal:build:production"
            },
            "local": {
              "browserTarget": "Portal:build:local"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "local"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Portal:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "4ab02e64-d731-4ff1-bf59-099f395e205e"
  }
}
```

And my Routes is like below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterPageComponent, canActivate: [PreventLoginGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent, canActivate: [PreventLoginGuard] },
  { 
    path: '', component: HomePageComponent, 
    canActivate: [PreventUnauthorizedAccessGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: NextToWatchPageComponent
      },
      { 
        path: 'show/:id', 
        component: ShowPageComponent 
      },
      { 
        path: 'search', 
        component: SearchPageComponent 
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

How can I fix this? It looks like a very stupid problem to have, and I've never run into this kind of problem before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your Problem may be that you havent set your app_base_href https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF

try this in your `angular.json`

```
{
  "projects": {
    "Portal": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "/"
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "/"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

OR-----------------------

in your main.ts/app.ts

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my/app'}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

OR-----------------------------------------------

in your index.html

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <!-- Other head elements -->
</head>
```

Comment: The third option worked! First option doesn't seem to be a thing though, maybe it was before but the app didn't even start after adding `baseHref` option. Thanks!